# Does Kaneki pop his knuckles or break them?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Initially, I used to think that he popped his knuckles, but the noise is simply too loud. Also, considering the gruesome origin of his white-haired avatar, I am inclined to think he breaks  them instead.

Does Kaneki pop his knuckles, or break them?

Answer (score 1):

Reddit has answered this for me: Also other websites.

I also managed to do it myself.

> "It's some kind of gestural tick that psyches them for battle. **Kaneki started doing as a result of Yamori always doing it when he was torturing him**, and Yamori picked it up from the human investigator who tortured him. Naki also does it, on a different finger as a tribute and to mimic Yamori."
>   Source:https://www.reddit.com/r/TokyoGhoul/comments/314hjz/why_does_jason_and_kaneki_crack_their_fingers/#s 
>  Reddit user:                                      [oredaore](https://www.reddit.com/user/oredaore)
>   “*Cracks Finger*” is a gestural Tic shown by Ken Kaneki, Naki, and Yamori. It's a habit started by Yamori's torturer, then imitated by Yamori, Naki, and Kaneki.
>   
> In the anime “Tokyo Ghoul”, Yamori cracks his finger every time he tortures Ken Kaneki. This teaches him to crack his own fingers after his escape. 
> [image]
>   I didn't want to do this but here (Text below reddit post): http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/cracks-finger
>   Image found here: [Sacbee-health-and-medicine](http://www.sacbee.com/news/local/health-and-medicine/tj173/picture52959545/alternates/FREE_1140/knucklegraphicCS5%20(3)) 
>  An actual video of someone doing it: [Youtube](https://youtu.be/9AQXe-3X67g?t=4)

Comment: They've answered why does he crack his knuckles. I'm asking does he crack them or break them by breaking I meant fracturing.

Comment: @Avnish Kabaj Edited to include full answer and example

Comment: @AvnishKabaj Cracking joins can be pretty loud sometimes, especially if you do it frequently and with excess force. Also note that anime can shift around sound volume for the benefit of the audience, such as whispers being loud, or characters way too far apart to be talking at normal volumes doing so. The sound could be amplified to better emphasis its intensity, since even ones that are so loud they echo in real life are usually not intense, but coincidental.

Comment: @Ryan Yep, I was doing it in my EP exam to help concentrate after I learned how to do it.